# Convert DateTime.Now to Time ago C#

Tags: c#, date

I'm working on simple asp.net mvc website, that shows user's post.
I'm saving the post details in the DB including uploaded date.

```
DateTime dateTimeNow = DateTime.Now;
newPost.Feed_Upload_Date = dateTimeNow;
DB.Post.Add(newPost);
DB.SaveChanges();
```

Now in my View when I'm showing the date, it shows me something like this

**"1/21/2019 4:29:58 PM"**

What I want to achieve is to convert this time in my Database into something like "1 day ago".
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can either implement it yourself or use [Humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer#humanize-datetime) library:

```
DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-30).Humanize() => "yesterday"
DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-2).Humanize() => "2 hours ago"
DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(30).Humanize() => "tomorrow"
DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(2).Humanize() => "2 hours from now"
DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1).Humanize() => "an hour from now"
```

Comment: Really appreciated for the fast reply, but how can I use this if I'm showing the the datetime from my DB like this..                                                                 
                @foreach (Post item in Model.PostV)
                                {
                                    <p>@item.Feed_Upload_Date</p>
                                }

Comment: `@item.Feed_Upload_Date.Humanize()`

Comment: not working....

Comment: You are probably missing an using statement in Razor template. Or create a view model you will fill with the values that should be displayed.

Comment: I've already added "@using Humanizer;" but when I type @item.Feed_Upload_Date.i do not get a Humanize option, I tried it in the home controller it's working perfectly.

Comment: Did you try it nevertheless? **Intellisense** not working on razor views doesn't necessarily mean that it won't work

Comment: If it still does not work, you might want to read [this part (Use in ASP.NET 4.x MVC Views)](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer#use-in-aspnet-4x-mvc-views)

Comment: thanks Rafalon,I edited the web.config file and it worked perfectly

Comment: Is there any way to show previous date as yesterday and time, ex., "Yesterday 4.10pm"? currently humanizer just shows as Yesterday...

Comment: @Krishnakumar I guess you'll have to concatenate it with the time info...